# Вырезаются теги в DLE

Tags: php, dle

Редактирую новость и хочу добавить фрейм `<iframe width="510" height="400" src="http://lll.ll" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>`.

В результате `DLE` тупо его вырезает в независимости,в короткой он новости или 'длинной'.
Версия 10.6

Как решить?

Comment: может стоит задуматься почему вырезается этот тег, возможно он не нужен?

Comment: @Serge Esmanovic Нужен.Ну мне сейчас точно необходим

Answer (score 1):

В файле `/engine/classes/parse.class.php` ищем строку

```
var $tagBlacklist = array('applet', 'body', 'bgsound', 'base', 'basefont', 'frame', 'frameset', 'head', 'html', 'id', 'iframe', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'link', 'meta', 'name', 'script', 'style', 'title', 'xml');
```

и удаляем оттуда **'iframe'**

Comment: Что-то ему фиолетово,мне кажется

Comment: попробуйте поиском по файлу поискать вхождение 'iframe'. может еще где есть список блокировки